# Android Volley ImageLoader - How to use Basic HTTP Authorization?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to use Volley's `NetworkImageView` to load images from my REST API that needs Basic HTTP Authorization. So i need to add headers to HTTP Request.

I've made up following approaches:

**Override `Request.getHeaders()`** - as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819911/2203164).
This would be fine, but the problem is that `ImageLoader` has `new ImageRequest()` hardcoded so I can't pass my `Request` implementation into `ImageLoader` and it cannot be easily inherited and tweaked (the method i'd need to reimplement uses private properties).

The solution is to modify Volley library itself (what i'd like to avoid).

**Use Custom HttpClientStack** - as described [here](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-volley-android-with-external-httpclient-4-2-x/). 
Using this approach i'd be able to intercept HTTP comunication and add necessary headers. But I think this is not the right way to do - I'd loose automatic selection of HttpClient by Volley (Gingerbread vs. HC and IC).

---

Is there some simplier way to achive this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have overriden `getHeaders()` as well. So far I haven't found a way to do that more easily.

See this example https://github.com/njzk2/VolleyTwitter/blob/master/src/com/njzk2/twitterbrowser/TokenRequest.java of an overriden Request to include the Authorization header.

From Volley code, I don't see any way of adding custom headers if not by overriding the Request object.

Moreover, I don't see how it can be easily added given the structure of Volley, as for the Images, ImageRequests are created by the ImageLoader.

If I were to modify Volley to allow this, I would make it possible to use a custom class extends ImageRequest in the ImageLoader. The anonymous ImageRequest class in ImageLoader makes it a bit complicated, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's pity that no simplier way exists. I'll do it the way you suggested - by modification of ImageLoader to use custom ImageRequest class (by creating and passing to ImageLoader a ImageRequestFactory). If I'm right, the anonymous are just Listeners passed to ImageRequest, not ImageRequest itself, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: there is an anonymous ImageRequest to call onGetImageSuccess(cacheKey, response); in onResponse (though I would have put that directly in ImageRequest, or even in Request.)

Answer (score 8):

I think HTTP stacks are the way to go. There is no loss of automatic HttpClient selection if you do your overrides based on SDK version, exactly like Volley does.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        HurlStack stack = new HurlStack() {
            @Override
            public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> headers)
                throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

                headers.putAll(MyApp.getAuthParams());

                return super.performRequest(request, headers);
            }
        };

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), stack);

    } else {
        HttpClientStack stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("volley/0")) {
            @Override
            public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> headers)
                throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

                headers.putAll(MyApp.getAuthParams());

                return super.performRequest(request, headers);
            }
        };

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), stack);
    }
```

See [Volley source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-5.1.0_r3/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/Volley.java) (line 53).

Comment: As part of Android M release  , HttpResponse class removed from sdk