# Digest Authentication with Volley? Is it possible?

Tags: android, rest, authentication, android-volley, digest

I was trying to follow the example from the question ["How does one use Basic Authentication with this library?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16817980/662581)

Here is my **`getHeaders()`** function

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String creds = String.format("%s:%s","MyEmail","MyPassword");
    String auth = "Digest " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    params.put("Authorization", auth);
    params.put("MY-API-TOKEN", "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");
    return params;
}
```

But I keep getting the **Error 401**

I'm using [Philsturgeon's Codeigniter RestServer](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) for my RestApi

I know that:

> Basic and Digest is just putting a header that looks like this
>   "Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" in Basic and more
>   complicated in digest

But I don't seem to be able to do it. So, **How can I do a Digest Authentication using Android-Volley?**