# Why Android Studio prompt “Method doesn't override its superclass”?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, overriding

I want to use volley to build http connection with authentication. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980454/5835947) I add the segment

```
  @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        String creds = String.format("%s:%s","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
                        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                        params.put("Authorization", auth);
                        return params;
                    }
```

in Anonymous Inner Class `StringRequest` , and it looks like:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {


//the segment below is what I add 
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String creds = String.format("%s:%s","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
                String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                params.put("Authorization", auth);
                return params;
            }

//the segment above is what I add 
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
});
```

However, IDE hints that `getHeaders()` doesn't override its superclass.

Why?I found that StringRequest extends class `Request<String>`, and the latter does have a method called `getHeaders()`.

Comment: Are you extending the class `Request`? E.G. `public class GetUser extends Request<User>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding `public Map<String, String> getHeaders()` inside a new instance of `Response.Listener<String>` instead of `Request<String>` and `Response.Listener<String>` does not have such method (only `onResponse(String)`).