# Django Rest Auth Token in Android Volley

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, android-volley, django-rest-auth

So I'm running into a problem when calling `rest-auth/user/`.

I am able to login and obtain the key from said login, but from that I'm not sure how to use it in regards to `rest-auth/user/`. I've tried using it with `GET` in volley, as well as `POST`ing it in volley. But everytime I try to do so, I get a 403 back saying credentials were not provided. I've also tried saving the token to Android's `SharedPreferences`.

I'm not sure what could be wrong or how to fix this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
getUserQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject();

try {
    jsObj.put("token", token);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, "http://hurst.pythonanywhere.com/supportal/rest-auth/user/", jsObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    result = response.getString("username");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
// add the request object to the queue to be executed
getUserQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: GET methods don't use a HTTP body, so I'm not sure what `jsObj` does as a parameter

Comment: Are you able to make the request using cURL or Postman? I would try that before writing it in Android

Comment: Using postman I was not able to get access via GET nor POST with the token I obtained, I get a response message of:

{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

It seems to run off session data / cookies in your browser, because if I login on my browser and try to access the user endpoint it returns the info of the account I logged in with.

Comment: I'm not sure about `/rest-auth/user`, but don't you need to use `/rest-auth/login/` first?

Comment: Postman does not keep cookies, as far as I know

Comment: Show your `REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES']` please.

Comment: Yes, I am able to create a volley connection to rest-auth/login and obtain the token that it returns, after that I send the token via `getIntent()` to this page. I'm thinking I have to save that token in the session to be able to access `/rest-auth/user`

Comment: Default Auth classes are listed as follows:
`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}`

Comment: what is the token you are recieving ?? JWT ?

Comment: I am using Django's default token-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

From comments it is clear that you are using different authentication schemes for rest, will explain these,

**SessionAuthentication**

For authenticating session authentication you need persistant cookie implementation in android volley, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library/25388897#25388897) for this, where `Set-Cookie` header is parsed from server api response & send over next requests.

**BasicAuthentication**

In Basic authentication scheme, username & password are send over every request ( after login ?), with `Authorization` header value ( Base64 encoded).To check how to implement this check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817980/how-does-one-use-basic-authentication-with-volley-on-android#18980454)

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String creds = String.format("%s:%s","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    params.put("Authorization", auth);
    return params;
}
```

**JSONWebTokenAuthenticatio‌​n**

In JWT authentication scheme, after successful login you will get a JWT token, you need to send this token in every request that need user authorization, for this to work, set `Authorization` header value with `JWT token_after_login`;Only difference with Basic authentication is how header is send.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String auth = "JWT " + token // token you will get after successful login
    params.put("Authorization", auth);
    return params;
}
```

Comment: I have experience in both platforms, so you can ask/comment if django related or android related clarification